# Using contextual information to plan route?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, osm2pgrouting

1. I downloaded the .osm map data, and I imported it to postgresql using the m2pgrouting.
2. I have a CSV file on violence data, with three attributes, nature of occurrence, latitude and longitude.

How do I plan a route avoiding these points of violence?

What should I do, can I cross the data with street network?

Does pgrouting topology allow this?

If not, which approach should I follow?

Comment: Yes, you can either make the cost really high for the segments in question or you could explicitly exlude nodes/links from the query that is passed to many pg_routing function, see [this link](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgRouting-concepts.html#inner-queries)

Comment: I tried to do this but I do not know how to use the points of violence that are in the CSV file.

Comment: Load them and snap them to the nearest road segment or road node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can explain with details.
Imagine you drive from node 7593 to node 17686 in a short way through edge 395166. You can perform the following query in pgrouting

```
with node_edge as (SELECT node, edge  FROM 
                pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM roads',7593,17686))
    select node_edge.node, node_edge.edge, roads.geom_way from node_edge, roads
                                    where node_edge.edge = roads_9_309_332.id
```

The result below
[image: First query]

Then something happened on the edge 395166.
You add a condition (where id<>395166) in the internal query so that the whole query will look like

```
 with node_edge as (SELECT node, edge  FROM 
                    pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM roads where id<>395166',7593,17686))
        select node_edge.node, node_edge.edge, roads.geom_way from node_edge, roads
                                        where node_edge.edge = roads_9_309_332.id
```

After performing that query you will see that the route will bypass the dangerous road segment.

[image: Bypass route]